# React Bootstrap Navbar not showing

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

i am trying to use React Bootstrap Navbar component. However, after installing bootstrap and pasting the example code, the navbar doesn't seem to load. i can't seem to wrap my head around how this doesn't work. any help will be greatly appreciated! my app.js code is as follows:

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import React from 'react';
import './assets/global.css';
import { Container, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
              Dank memes
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>,
  );
}
```

global.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: [Your code is working on my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-knuth-wkjrfv?file=/src/App.js). Did you install both `react-bootstrap` and `bootstrap` like `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`?

Comment: yes, followed the instructions on installing bootstrap with npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap

Comment: Ok, by the way, there is an extra comma in this line `</Navbar>,`. It might be related to this line.

Comment: still not working, for context, i am creating a near application with react as frontend, do you think it has any effect on the localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was that i installed react-bootstrap in the wrong folder. always check your directory guys!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem that you did not fix some of the react-bootstrap when you install them. Call npm audit fix --force and see if it works